# These errors are not resolving even there's no mistake it is not perfoming reorder

Tags: php

**Warning**:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\customer\data.php** on line **45**

**Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\customer\data.php** on line **51**

My Code

```
$qry = dbQuery("SELECT `orders_product`.`pd_id`, `op_quantity` FROM `orders_product` 
    INNER JOIN `products_detail` ON `products_detail`.`pd_id`=`orders_product`.`pd_id`
    WHERE orders_product.order_id = $id");
if(dbNumRows($qry)>0) {
    $cart="";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { $_SESSION['cart']="";}
    $result = dbFetchArray($qry);
    while($result = dbFetchArray($qry)) {
        $product_detail_id = $result["pd_id"];
        $order_quantity = $result["op_quantity"];
        // echo $product_detail_id;
        #print_r($result);

        if(array_key_exists($product_detail_id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
            $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_detail_id]['quantity'] + $order_quantity;
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_detail_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
        } else {
            $cart = array("pd_id"=>$product_detail_id, "quantity"=> $order_quantity);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_detail_id] = $cart;  
            print_r($cart);
        }
    }
      
}
$return = 1;
echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: You have `$_SESSION['cart']="";`. The cart is supposed to be an associative array, not a string.

Comment: When the parser gives you a Warning, the first thing you should realise is that you _probably made a mistake_. Firstly assuming you made no mistake is not a good attitude to take if you want to develop your skills.

Comment: It is very nice from PHP telling the line.

Comment: Besides the above, you have a strange way of adding `$order_quantity`. At the moment you do: `$q = $S + $oq; $S = $q;` Much simpler is: `$S = $S + $oq;` or even simpler: `$S += $oq;`

Answer (score 0):

#### First problem

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\customer\data.php on line 45

That's because you use `$_SESSION['cart']` with function `array_key_exists`. So when a person enters the website for the first time the variable `$_SESSION['cart']` is not set.

What you do then is assign an empty string.

```js
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { $_SESSION['cart']="";}
```

So then you use empty string with function `array_key_exists`.

**Solution**
To resolve this issue simply change

```js
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { $_SESSION['cart']="";}
```

to

```js
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { $_SESSION['cart']=array();}
```

#### Second problem

> Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\customer\data.php on line 51

Now, this is only a notice so that's not a big issue. It may not even be something wrong. After you change to not display errors it won't affect your website in any way.

But why is this showing? Again the same reason as with the previous problem. You assign empty string to variable `$_SESSION['cart']` but then you treat is as an array

```js
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_detail_id] = $cart;
```

When you change the assignment from empty string to empty array this issue will be solved as well.

By the way when you write a one line if statement a good practice is not to use the braces

So I would write it like

```js
$_SESSION['cart'] = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : [];
```

Or even better

```js
$_SESSION['cart'] = $_SESSION['cart'] ?? [];
```

But this is only php 7.0 and higher

I hope you understand now what was wrong and why. If you have any questions feel free to ask. I'll try to reply the best away I can.